# Silly Question on Definition of real solutions and real roots

Tags: roots, quadratics

For $a\neq0$, the equation $ax^2+b|x|+c=0$ has k real solutions and p real roots.

> Here, my doubt is what does the solution means and how it is different from real roots?

*Thanks for clearing my silly doubt.*

Comment: In this case, they are the same. Not a silly question at all!

Comment: Once you realized that $k=p$ always, were you wondering what the possible values of $k$ were?

Comment: @Lubin No, actually I wanted to know if there is any difference between these two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the same.

---

If you want to be *super* pedantic – don't be – the equation has solutions, not roots.

For those who like getting into pointless arguments, there's a reasonable case that a *function* has *roots* and no solutions, whereas an *equation* has *solutions* but no roots. But that's fighting the same sort of losing battle as the one fights who argues that "data" is a plural and not a mass noun; everyone is sure to ignore you if you try and impose this as a rule of grammar. You'd have a better chance of convincing people that "awesome" means "terrible and mighty" and not "brilliant and wonderful".